# Fabric for iOS app Development and Production

Tags: ios, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I have an application on the App Store (production environment), configured with Crashlytics from Fabric. As a consequence, I have a project configured in the Fabric dashboard with the list of users' crashes and activities.

Now, I want to launch a beta for private circle of users. I want this beta to be connected to Crashlytics in order to have details if it crash.

But if I do that all their crash will be reported in the same workflow of my production app. That is dirty, right ?

Both of the app have the same bundle Id. How could I do to set up my beta project without ruining my production project ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can by creating a different configuration.
here a gif video that I just recorded for you
http://g.recordit.co/N4Xp3I2vtZ.gif

In the gif I have duplicated the debug configuration, but I strongly recommend you to use the release one

Comment: Oh thanks. That seems to be a very good practice that I missed!
Just an add, thanks to configurations its possible to do cool stuff like here: http://nilsou.com/blog/2013/07/29/how-to-have-two-versions-of-the-same-app-on-your-device/